# FFmpeg: Video with crossfade slides and Move up / Move Down effect doesn't work correctly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm creating video from the images which have different sizes and orientations. 
Actually, I need to do video slides' animations based on the image orientation (aspect ratio). So, let's say I have 4 images with the following sizes:

***1.jpg  1280x1600  ( Top to bottom )***
***2.jpg  1280x1600  ( Bottom to Top )***
***3.jpg  1280x1600  ( Top to bottom )***
***4.jpg  1280x1280  ( No effect )***

Here is the *FFmpeg* command which I'm running

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex " \
[0]crop=1280:1280:ow:((ih-oh)/5)*t,format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[f0];
[1]crop=1280:1280:ow:(ih-oh)-((ih-oh)*t/5),format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[f1];
[2]crop=1280:1280:ow:((ih-oh)/5)*t,format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8/TB[f2];
[3]fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+12/TB[f3];
[0][f0]overlay[bg1];[bg1][f1]overlay[bg2];[bg2][f2]overlay[bg3];[bg3][f3]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 4:a -b:v 4000k -movflags +faststart -t 20 -s 1280x1280 out.mp4
```

Please have a look at the first seconds of the video

[image]

So, the crossfade, crop and the effect are working but as you can see, it keeps an unnecessary section at the bottom of the video. All other animations are shown in the above section

[image]

Not sure, but seems it's keeping the first image height (1600)?
Looking forward to any suggestion to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) filter:

[image]

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i cyan.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i magenta.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i yellow.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i black.jpg \
-i audio.mp4
-filter_complex \
"[0]crop=1280:1280[v1]; \
 [1]crop=1280:1280[v2]; \
 [2]crop=1280:1280[v3]; \
 [3]crop=1280:1280[v4]; \
 [v1][v2]xfade=wipedown:duration=1:offset=4[x1]; \
 [x1][v3]xfade=wipeup:duration=1:offset=8[x2]; \
 [x2][v4]xfade=wipedown:duration=1:offset=12,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 4:a -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

You can see a gallery of all transitions at [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade).

Comment: Seems that ```xfade``` is a new filter? I was needed to update the ```ffmpeg``` and it works perfectly. The animations up / down via crop and about 20 fade options. Saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: @ArmKh Yes, it is less than a week old.